# D630 laptop comes with Windows XP, but has a sticker for Vista on the bottom with a key

Tags: windows-vista, product-key

I'm thinking they didn't like the Vista, or something like that.

1. Can I use that product key on the bottom of my laptop to install *Windows Vista*, since it may have been installed before?
2. Why would there be a Vista sticker on the bottom while *Windows XP* is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of machines that came with Vista had a downgrade license, the Vista License will activate Windows Vista.
You are perfetcly entitled to install Vista using the COA on the bottom. Make sure you have the restore media for Windows XP as the Vista key will not activate XP if you wish to install it again.